# What is the correct setting for google drive sharing?

Tags: google-drive-api, sharing

Please suppose a situation. Organisation has a shared folder, with many people having access to sub folders some should not be able to edit/delete documents, but they should still be able to view and add documents to a folder.

Subsequently they should be able to share their own document with anyone (from the main folder "share list") but should not be able to share a document they were asked to join.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Drive, Sharing settings offer 3 options depending on the user to restrict access. Each document CREATED in a shared folder inherits the share preferences of the parent folder. However, each document's access settings can still be managed individually and changed accordingly as well. Following are the 3 options and the access they provide to users:

1. Can Edit - With this option the user has access to edit, delete and share the doc
2. Can Comment - With this option the user in neither able to edit, nor delete or share the doc. However, they can view and insert comments to the doc.
3. Can View - Users can see the file but they can't comment on it or edit it.

In both, Option 2 & 3, Users are not able to share the doc but they are able to request for access in case they want the doc to be shared with someone. This request will go to the owner of the document. For more info, please take a look at this [link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en).

Users with access to the parent folder might be able to see the document in the list, but if they haven't been given access to the document, they will not be able to open it. However, they might be able to request access to that document. Such access requests are forwarded to and handled by the owner of the document.

This [link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494886?hl=en) might help shed more light on the matter as well.